# How to list all sheets in opened Workbook in Workbook_Open event handler Sub?

Tags: vba, excel

When user opens a saved Workbook, I want to load data from my hidden sheet in it.

I thought I would use `Workbook_Open` Sub and load data from that worksheet from this Sub, but then this Sub is invoked, I do not have any Workbook yet.

Here is an example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Debug.Print "Open: " & Workbooks.Count 'prints 0 to console
End Sub
```

I also tried this approach:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   For Each sh In Sheets
      Debug.Print sh.name
      'prints only Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 and do not print the name of my data sheet.
   Next sh
End Sub
```

So my question is: how can I get a sheet by name when user opens a Workbook?

Comment: your example:

    `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Debug.Print "Open: " & Workbooks.Count 'prints 1 to console
       Debug.Print "Open: " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count 'prints 3 to console
    End Sub`

gives me for workbook count: 1, and for sheet count: 3 - the right numbers

Where did you put your Workbook_Open() Sub? in the worksheet, or in ThisWorkbook?

Comment: I created an Add-in (xlam file). I put this code in Add-in's 'ThisWorkbook'.

Comment: I think you should open the workbook first within your Add in

Comment: @tretom, sorry, I don't get it. What do you mean by saying that?

Comment: I meant, if you get 0 for Workbooks.Count, then you have no workbooks open. And so, before you try to reach one, you should open one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were simply missing some references.

I've just tested this and work nicely :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Debug.Print "Opened wB: " & Application.Workbooks.Count

   Dim wS As Worksheet

   Debug.Print "Sheets: "
   For Each wS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      Debug.Print wS.Name
   Next wS
End Sub
```